# How do you determine where to spend your 100%?

Tags: sql-server

The execution plan always produces a result of 100%, so is there a rule of thumb for which section is where you want the highest percentage?

For instance, if I do a SELECT statement, I can see that

```
03% Hash Match
02% Hash Match
10% Hash Match
01% RID Lookup
09% RID Lookup 
04% Index Seek
07% Index Seek (Nonclustered)
01% Clustered Index seek
18% Clustered Index seek
35% Key lookup (Clustered)
01% Nested Loops
```

You get the idea.  Forgive me if I left one or two out.  So my question is: Is that good or not?  If I play with the SELECT statement, I'm sure the statistics will change, but they'll always add up to 100, so I don't know which category I want to have the highest percentage.

Comment: Methinks the real question is "Do I have an issue with the current performance of the query?"  If not, then you need not engage in premature optimization.  If so, the percentages help you determine where your attention might be best directed for the greatest payback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really a goal to, say, "push 100% to a clustered index seek" but what you should be doing is focusing on the most expensive operators and trying to make them more efficient. That is, of course, if the query is exhibiting a performance problem in the first place. There is always going to be a "most expensive" operator in any query plan - but how expensive is the overall query? Are you spending time on your heaviest hitters? How do you know? Or are you looking at that 35% operator and trying to squeeze an extra nanosecond out of a query that already runs in 2ms?

Also, don't rely on *estimated* execution plans for this; generate *actual* plans (which will contain information about estimates as well, giving you an idea of how far off SQL Server might be).

One comment for your specific case: you want to do what you can to get rid of any RID or key lookups. This means potentially adding clustered indexes to your heaps (do you have a valid use case for your heaps?), and potentially adding or changing existing indexes on your tables with clustered indexes.

I highly recommend you grab Grant Fritchey's free eBook, SQL Server Execution Plans:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/books/65831/

I also highly recommend you download [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view.asp) and give it a try. There are several advantages over the SSMS showplan that can help you identify and fix plan issues more quickly:

- color scale the most expensive operators
- show cost breakdowns by CPU, I/O, or both
- always get the % right ([many cases](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/267530/ssms-execution-plan-sometimes-exceeds-100) where SSMS [adds to way more than 100%](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/370798/query-plan-iterator-cost-percentage-way-off))
- show more meaningful information on exchanges (more deterministic line widths, and show row count or data size without having to look in tooltips)
- highlight differences between estimated and actual rows
- highlight expensive operators such as lookups (and identify columns that are missing from the index)
- when generating actual plans, we include runtime metrics such as CPU / duration / reads
- and a ton of other features I won't belabor here...

*Disclaimer: I work for SQL Sentry*

Comment: Thanks Aaron.  This gives me a lot to read.  Thank you very much.